# What's wrong with this JavaScript code (functions)?

Tags: javascript, function, return

Sorry for being difficult, but I actually have 2 questions of pretty much same type...

1st question:
Why are my last three functions in this code not working...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Skriver ut en strengen "Bananer og epler er ikke det samme!"
        document.write("Bananas and apples are not the same! ");
        //Variabelnavnet kan kun inneholde bokstaver, tall, og understrek. Variabelnavnet kan ikke begynne med et tall.
        var banana1 = "rotten"; 
        var banana2 = "good";
        document.write("One banana was " + banana1 + " and the other was " + banana2 + ", and they both know the song \"I'm yellow and I hate it\" very well.<br />");
        //En pop-up melding i samarbeid med XHTML.
        function bananas() 
        {alert ("Wow, what a loser u are!");}
        function cherries() 
        {alert ("That's better!");}
        //Flere parametere.
        function pineapples(one, two){
        document.write(one + " are as sweet as " + two + "<br />");
        }
        pineapples("Pineapples", "kiwis");
        pineapples("Watermelons", "citrons");
        pineapples("Dades", "apricots");
        }
        function waterMelons(){
        document.write("I loooove watermelons!");
        }            
        function ciTrons(){
        document.write("But citrons...!");
        }
        function start(){
        waterMelons();
        ciTrons();
        }
        start();
    </script>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Click me if u like bananas" onclick="bananas()"/>
        <input type="button" value="Click me if u like cherries" onclick="cherries()"/>
    </form>     
</body>
</html>
```

But when I put the last three functions in a seperate file, like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function waterMelons(){
        document.write("I loooove watermelons!");
        }            
        function ciTrons(){
        document.write(" But citrons...!");
        }
        function start(){
        waterMelons();
        ciTrons();
        }
        start();
</script>       
</body>
</html>
```

It's working! Why!?

2nd question

Is something wrong with this code or am I as dumb as a rotten fruit? Why doesn't it return the value "20"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addNumbers(a,b,c){
        var d = a+b+c;
        return d;
        }
        ducument.write(addNumbers(2,6,12));
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problems are `typos`, in the first case you're using extra `}`:

```
    function pineapples(one, two){
      document.write(one + " are as sweet as " + two + "<br />");
    }
      pineapples("Pineapples", "kiwis");
      pineapples("Watermelons", "citrons");
      pineapples("Dades", "apricots");
    } <-- THIS IS WRONG
```

In the second case you're using `ducument` instead of `document`:

```
ducument.write(addNumbers(2,6,12)); <-- MUST BE document
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much!! What a blind idiot I am, LOL! Unreal! Been staring at the screen for hours looking for typos! LOL! TY!!!

Comment: @Deezhan don't worry you're welcome. Indeent the code can help in this cases and also use the js console `:)`